# What request/response communication pattern should I use between 2 .NET softwares?

Tags: c#, .net, communication

I have a console app, let's call it the "Processor". It's crunching data and keeping an overall state for some data.

There is also a website to display and modify this state

But I don't want the state to be hosted within the web app, that's why they are hosted separately.

I am not sure how I should communicate between the webapp and the console app.

RabbitMQ does the job to do some pushes from the Processor to the website, which uses SignalR to update the web UI.

What is missing: A way to communicate from the webapp to the console app to do some update on data.

What communication pattern should I use for that?

Comment: If SignalR is already there, you should know it is bidirectional.

Comment: @LexLi SignalR is there in the webapp only, for communication between the browser (javascript SignalR client) and the webapp server. Not between the webapp and the consoleapp. Am I missing something?

Comment: If the existing SignalR hub is for that purpose only, then create your own SignalR hub for inter-process communication is nothing hard (as you already know how it works).

Comment: @LexLi Thanks - so I guess my console app should be a web app if I understand correctly...@Konamiman and you seem to be pointing towards that solution path

Comment: Very very strange that you don't know that any app types (console/web/others) can subscribe to a SignalR hub. The answer below simply makes the situation complex. Your console has no need to host an HTTP server as it says. No no. Subscribe to a SignalR hub from the console is adequate in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your console application open a simple HTTP server on a previously agreed (or configurable) port, and then your website can communicate with your application by doing what websites do best: issuing HTTP requests (using Ajax, typically). You can implement the server all by yourself (take a look at [the HttpListener class](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.7.1) as a starting point) or use any existing framework such as [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org) (or [browse the NuGet gallery for "http-server"](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22http-server%22)).